# Display Pandas DF in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

I am working to create a GUI in Tkinter and am trying to display a Pandas Dataframe in the main root window when the specific button is pressed.

I currently have a 'Calculate' button that when pressed it displays the dataframe but it opens in a new top level window.

Here is my current code:

```
def calculate_button(x, y, n, m):
    global results
    results = funct(x, y, n, m)
    print(results)
    
    results_output = tk.Toplevel()
    results_output.title('TKinter App')
    results_window = Table(results_output, dataframe=results, showtoolbar=False, showstatusbar=False)
    results_window.show()
```

How do i made the adjustment to have this be placed on the root TKinter window using .grid so it aligns with everything else on the root. Is this possible?

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it is possible to display the Pandas DataFrame on the main root window using `grid` so that it aligns with other widgets. To achieve this, you can follow these steps:

1. Create a new frame inside the main root window where you want to display the DataFrame.
2. Instead of using `Toplevel`, use the new frame to display the DataFrame.
3. Use `grid` layout manager to place the new frame in the desired position within the root window.

Here's the modified code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from pandastable import Table  # Assuming you are using pandastable to display DataFrames

def calculate_button(x, y, n, m):
    global results
    results = funct(x, y, n, m)
    print(results)
    
    # Create a new frame inside the root window to display the DataFrame
    results_frame = tk.Frame(root)  # Replace 'root' with the actual name of your main root window
    results_frame.grid(row=row_number, column=column_number, padx=10, pady=10)  # Adjust row and column number as per your requirement
    
    # Create the PandasTable inside the new frame
    results_window = Table(results_frame, dataframe=results, showtoolbar=False, showstatusbar=False)
    results_window.show()

# Create your Tkinter main root window
root = tk.Tk()

# Add other widgets and layouts using grid or pack as necessary

# Example usage of the calculate_button function
calculate_button(x, y, n, m)

# Start the main event loop
root.mainloop()
```

Make sure to replace `'root'` with the actual name of your main root window, and adjust the `row` and `column` numbers in `results_frame.grid` according to where you want the DataFrame to be displayed.

With these changes, the DataFrame will be displayed inside the new frame within the main root window using the `grid` layout manager.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Saunak Ghosh!

Both of your answers so far here appear likely to be entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and continue to be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.